# escaping the special characters without knowing the position batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a requirement to execute a batch file with the arguments. the problem occuring here is I am not sure what special characters and at what place it can occur. I have gone through possibly all the answers here but still unable to fix the issue. Any help is appreciated.

Command that i am trying to run within the batch file

```
CALL E:\myscript.bat -run e:\param -password %PASSWORD%
```

where PASSWORD is the variable storing the password and it can be having any special characters at any position.

Comment: First thing I'd ask is if you've tried doublequoting the password.

Comment: I tried that but didn't work though.

Comment: What didn't work? prove it! I'm not staying here all day guessing all of the things you may have tried, but couldn't be bothered telling me about, before I suggested it! Please provide a [mcve], i.e. some example commands with some example passwords, which are failing for you. And the content of `myscript.bat` which is handling those input parameters/arguments.

Comment: I guess you suggested to put the password within doublequotes, that actually didn't work. Plus the password can contain any combination of special characters and alphanumerics. Ex : !abc23%$ .

Comment: Is your actual file used to pass parameters really a batch file or an executable?

Comment: Please revisit my previous comment Akash, I have given you an opportunity to fix your question, such that it is answerable, if you fail to do so, I will be voting to close it. Currently you have no idea what argument will relate to the password in `myscript.bat`, had you used `Call "myscript.bat" -run "E:\param" -password "%PASSWORD%"`, you would know that the password content would be available as `%~4` within that file. I'm going to bet that you've just used `%4`, and those surrounding doublequotes have broken it!

Comment: The important part is the script `E:\myscript.bat`, how it handles the password/argument at all. Is it even able to handle passwords with speical characters? What is done with the password, is it transfered to another program? I would be very surprised if `E:\myscript.bat` can handle complex passwords

Comment: A percent sign inside a string is always (and exclamation mark _could_ be) a problem if used as `set "PASSWORD=!abc23%$"`;  Use `set "PASSWORD=!abc23%%$"` (double percent sign). For `call`, quadruple it as `set "PASSWORD=!abc23%%%%$"` …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I understood your question, it would be:

- You want to identify, without having to have specific argument
  positions, what each argument represents.

Or:

- You want to find a solution to handle the arguments so that they do
  not result in errors because they contain special characters

Anyway, I will answer both.

You have some alternatives for doing so, some may be more ideal than others depending on how you are handling your code and its purpose.
In case you identify the arguments and what they represent, you can:

```
set args=%*
```

Some things may help you make your code stable while using an wildcard without its effect. Like:

```
set "args=%args:&=^&"
```

But the most important thing is to keep the code without quotes. In fact, the use of CALL is not necessary if you are not doing it within a script.

```
set "args=%args:"=%
```

The next thing to do is to identify the parameters. We can do this both in a crude way and in a simpler way, which would be defining each argument with its own variable, such as: `arg1=%1`, `arg2=%2`...

You can now pass all parameters into a treatment and reconstruction session.

Assuming you want to identify -password:

---during a FOR loop to catch and make the same processes at every arg---
(which I can only guess because you didn’t show the code or anything like that)

```
if "!arg[%%x]:~0,1!" equ "-" (
if "!arg[%%x]:-=!" equ "password" set /a x=%%x+1&set "password=!arg[%x%]!"
if "!arg[%%x]:-=!" equ "run" set /a x=%%x+1&set "run=!arg[%x%]!"
...
)
```

Obviously there are some things that can improve in this code, but you have shown almost nothing for us to use as a reference to answer, so that's all I can do.

***Hope this helps,

K.***

Comment: You could mark the answer as accepted if helped.

Comment: Hey that's what i was looking for. Perfectly worked like charm. :)